# Using XML in SQL Server Reporting service + Textbox

Tags: sql, xml, reporting-services

I am having data in xml as column  in my table.
I am retriveing the value

```
select * from customer
```

But my customer column value looks like this

```
<customer exception ="Sam"/>
<customer exception ="Jam"/>
```

I need to specify the first two letters of this exception in my sql reports textbox as 
(S,J)

How can I achieve this in SSRS reports

Comment: Maybe it's because I am on my phone, but I don't see what you are saying.  You say that your customer column "looks like this", but that's all I have.

Comment: Use the "101010" button to highlight code please